# Rendering MPTT structure with open/close possibility in django template

Tags: python, css, django, vue.js, django-templates

I need to render my MPTT model as tree with dropdown (open/close every node that contains children) possibility and buttons that will open/close all the nodes in that tree in 1 click.

I tried to find some ready-to-use examples, but best that I found is this:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          {% recursetree thecategories %}
          {% if node.level == 0 %}
          {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
          <!-- Let op: <li> tag wordt steeds onderaan aangevuld, ander werkt het niet...-->
          <li class="dropdown nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="mainBarItem">{{ node.ctg_Title }}<span class="caret"></span> </span></a>
            {% else %}
          <li><a href="#" class="mainBarItem">{{ node.ctg_Title }}</a>
            {% endif %}

            {% else %}
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="nav-label">{{ node.ctg_Title }}<span class="caret"></span></span></a>
            {% else %}
          <li><a href="#">{{ node.ctg_Title }}</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
            <ul class="children dropdown-menu">
              {{ children }}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
          </li>

          {% endrecursetree %}
        </ul>
```

with some CSS and JS, but it is not that I need.
Actually I need to render just one tree at a time. I'm passing variable {{ product }} in my template that is just a root node. And for now I have this code from MPTT docs example that just render it as a list:

```
{% for product,structure in product.get_family|tree_info %}
    {% if structure.new_level %}
        <ul>
        <li>{% else %}</li>
        <li>{% endif %}
    {% if product.purchased %}
        <span style="color: #f5e642">{{ product.code }}</span>
    {% else %}
        {{ product.code }}
    {% endif %}
    {% for level in structure.closed_levels %}</li></ul>{% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Also tried Nestable2, but it doesn't work for me, and IDK why. It renders as it should with drag and drop possibility but without possibility to open/close parent nodes (buttons are rendered but doesn't work).
I'm weak at front end development (Know just the basics of JS).
I thought maybe I can use some ready-to-use components in Jquery or Vue.js or anything else? Or will it be easier just in vanilla js? I appreciate any help and advices.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387943/how-to-include-dropdown-menu-with-django-mptt-in-template

Comment: As I said I already tried this, it's not that I actually need

Comment: This is probably not a good question for jQuery developers.

Comment: Oh...I asked it in jQuery section? Maybe I can move it to the django section somehow?

Comment: There are five tags on your post.  javascript
jquery
django
vue.js
django-templates

Comment: Okay, thanks, now I know how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone interested in how I did it, here is a simple code:

HTML

```
<ul id="myUL">
    {% recursetree product.get_family %}
        <li>
            {% if node.is_leaf_node %}
                <span class="leaf">{{ node.code }}</span>
            {% else %}
                <span class="caret parent">{{ node.code }}</span>
                <ul class="nested">
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul, #myUL {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/* Remove margins and padding from the parent ul */
#myUL {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Style the caret/arrow */
.caret {
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none; /* Prevent text selection */
}

/* Create the caret/arrow with a unicode, and style it */
.caret::before {
    content: "\25B6";
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

/* Rotate the caret/arrow icon when clicked on (using JavaScript) */
.caret-down::before {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* Hide the nested list */
.nested {
    display: none;
}

/* Show the nested list when the user clicks on the caret/arrow (with JavaScript) */
.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Javascript

```
'use strict';

var togglers = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < togglers.length; i++) {
    togglers[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
        this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
    });
}
```